# Vim foldexpr for including multiline function signatures

Tags: c++, vim, folding

I'd like to fold source code such that a function signature that spans multiple lines is included in the function fold. In C++ for example, I'd like

```
void ClassName::FunctionName(LongType1 LongArgument1,
                             LongType2 LongArgument2,
                             LongType3 LongArgument3) {
  ...
}
```

to be folded to

```
+-- 5 lines: void ClassName::FunctionName [...]
```

rather than

```
void ClassName::FunctionName(LongType1 LongArgument1,
                             LongType2 LongArgument2,
+-- 3 lines: LongType3 LongArgument3) [...]
```

where `+` denotes a closed fold.

The only solution I could think of was to use a function for `foldexpr` that effectively iterates over surrounding lines looking for a `{` or `}`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My [VimFold4C](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C) plugin will display something closer to what you were looking for (3 years ago...)

```
+void ClassName::FunctionName(LongType1 LongArgument1, LongType2 LongArgument2, LongType3 LongArgument3) ----------
```

The foldtext is not perfect for the moment, but it may be improved on this topic in the future. Any way, this time you'll get only one line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.  The second issue is probably the FoldText, where you're on right track.  Adding code to parse subsequent lines for text and for closing brace is best way to do it.  If you're worried that it's going to slow things down, don't.  I have foldtext functions where I do far, far more than that and it doesn't affect things perceptibly.  (The fold text function is probably not called as often as you think; it's only maintained for viewable lines.)

EDIT: The fold text part is even easier than that.  If you position cursor at first brace of signature doing `normal! va{y` will put the braces part of sig in @".  Then just get pre-brace part and append `join(split((@","\n"))` to it.

The other issue, the main issue, is the folding rule.  You appear to want function folds to be on first line of function signature even for multi-line signatures.  You can try using the foldexpression method to get closer to what you want.  This foldexpr would work if every function (and only functions) began with 'void' in leftmost column:

```
set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum+1)=~'^void'?'<0':'1'
```

Since that's not realistic you can define some pattern that will match all lines that you want as collapsible lines, i.e, the first lines of function defs along with whatever other fold blocks you want:

```
function! VimFoldLevel(line)
    "check if this is the last line in a fold block
    if getline(a:line + 1) =~ '[pattern that matches first fold lines]'
        return '<0'
    else
        return '1'
    endif
endfunction
```

Then make sure to set foldexpr equal to your foldlevel func: `set foldexpr=VimFoldLevel(v:lnum)`

And also set your foldmethod to expr:  `set foldmethod=expr`

There are probably other ways to do it but that's the one that comes to mind. . .   If there's some commonly used folding method (e.g., syntax) that's used for c++ and which has different levels of folding, you'd want to modify that.  Example I gave offers only 1 level of folds, function completely folded or completely unfolded.

Comment: I'm not so concerned with the fold text, I just want the entire function signature to be folded. The problem with your proposed function `VimFoldLevel` is the pattern choice. It would be very difficult to find an expression that would match only the desired lines. You can't, for example, match against the return type because you could have any arbitrary class name present. This is why I thought it would be necessary to look around locally to get a better sense of the context of the current line. I was hoping to avoid this, but it seems like the only option.